# How to export data to .xlsx format, without using Open XML format?

Tags: excel, .net-2.0, openxml

Help me to export the data to an Excel. I have a list of data in a Data table.

I would like to export it to Excel .xlsx format, without using Open XML.

Programming Language: C# .Net Version: 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Found this ....

```
public static void DataGridToExcel(DataTable tbl)
{
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Clear();
foreach (DataColumn c in tbl.Columns)
{
    context.Response.Write(c.ColumnName + ";");
}
context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        context.Response.Write(r[i].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + ";");
    }
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=export.csv");
context.Response.End();
}
```

This will output from ASP.NET a response with a CSV file that Excel 2007 can open. If you want you can change the extension to mimic excel and it should work just by replacing the following lines:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=export.xlsx");
```

A CSV is the easiest way if you don't need to do anything complex. If you do require it to truly be a Excel 2007 file in the native format, you will need to use an Office library to build it or convert it from the CSV and then serve/save it.